# How to redirect www to non-www using certbot for HTTPS & nginx

Tags: nginx, https, ssl-certificate, nginx-config, certbot

I'm trying to redirect www to non-www but it doesn't work. I've tried various answers from similar questions but those haven't worked.

I have SSL cert using certbot for 3 domains `example.com`, `www.example.com` and `admin.example.com`.

This is my current config, which works for non-www and admin, however www.example.com doesn't work.

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect to non-www
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# non-www
server {

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
# CMS
server {

    server_name admin.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I use DigitalOcean where both admin & non-www points to my droplet and www.example.com has a CNAME record to example.com (non-www).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, the www.example.com and example.com should be in one server block.

Secondly, you need to add this in your `#non-www` server configuration blog

```
if ($host = 'www.example.com') {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Thirdly, to redirect all requests to HTTPS, `server_name` must be added in your `# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS` block.

Finally, your NGINX Configuration file will look like this

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com admin.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# non-www
server {

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    if ($host = 'www.example.com') {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
# CMS
server {

    server_name admin.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Once you update your NGINX configuration file, restart NGINX:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: `if ($host = 'www.example.com') {return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;}` within the server block did the trick for me!